# переход с http на https

Tags: http, https

```
RewriteEngine on
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https SERVER_PORT=443
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

куда здесь вставлять ссылку на незащищенный сайт http://akmo.ru, а куда на защищенный https://akmo.ru/ или вообще что-то другое требуется, не понимаю

Comment: Никуда, это просто нужно положить как есть в файл `.htaccess` в корень сайта. Apache сам должен подставить домен

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в корне сайта уже имеется ".htaccess". Вам нужно найти там уже существующую строку - "RewriteEngine on" и подставить после неё следующие строки.
Правда нужно иметь SSL-сертификат для этого, иначе хуже только сделаете.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```